# Does 'game' have a meaning related to farming?

Tags: vocabulary

> Most of the land in Namibia belongs to the whites. 
>   To Afrikaners who are descendants of European colonists. 
>   They raise cattle and game.

'They raise cattle' I can understand, but I don't know how to define the meaning of the word 'game' in this context.

Does that mean some kind of business related to farming?

Comment: I think they mean: game: wild animals and birds that are hunted for food or sport: *game birds* - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game

Comment: See the following usage: *Rinderpest, German for "cattle plague," is a viral disease that strikes ruminants, both cattle and game such as buffalo, wildebeest, and large antelope such as eland and kudu.* https://books.google.it/books?id=91CjrLHlE_8C&pg=PA101&dq=%22cattle+and+game%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGq9SytZPlAhXFa1AKHcdKAtEQ6AEIWzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22cattle%20and%20game%22&f=false

Comment: thanks a lot :) @user067531

Comment: In the African context the idea that people can "raise game" seems a little odd to me as my understanding of African game animals is that they are genuinely wild. In the British context a lot of game birds (particularly pheasant) are only semi-wild. In the UK pheasants are hatched, grown, released then intensively fed even though they otherwise live autonomously.

Answer (score 2):

From Cambs online Dictionary:

> **[Game](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game)** noun (ANIMALS) 
>   Wild animals and birds that are hunted for food or sport

edit: just spotted this was also linked in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515179/they-raise-cattle-and-game/515191#comment1249862_515179) by user067531! (Although unsure how I missed it)